# Can anyone explain me the ILS Approach Chart of my Airport?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

I'm from Lucknow, India (VILK) and recently I experienced my very first CAT IIIB  ILS landing at my homebase. Ever since I'm more curious to know about this technology and how it works.

I was able to get the charts of various approaches type at my base but I was interested in the ILS CATII/IIIB type but I don't understand a single word mentioned in the chart.

My flight took 4 holding patterns at 11000 feet just like how its drawn on the chart and then we flew towards east and descended to 7000 feet on our initial approach and then turned south and finally west to runway 27 at 3000 to 2500 feet and continued at 2350 feet for sometime and then descended to land.

The arrow over airport looks exactly how we took made four holding patterns before landing exactly like its drawn in the chart but I don't understand if what I'm making of it is actually what it is or not.

[image: ILS Cat III/B Approach plate of LUCKNOW (VILK)]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120456/discussion-between-avgeeker-and-jpe61).

Comment: One thing that seems to make it easier is the arrows point *to* the compass direction.  It was confusing at first that the landing seemed to be *to* the east.  I was wondering if the "11000 foot holding pattern" was drawn in or did you just descend and enter the 3500 foot bearing 089 min oval?